# Block child process from simulating user keyboard input

Tags: c#, process, keyboard

I have been tasked with integrating an existing executable (cannot modify) into an application we manage.  The integration went smoothly until I tried to run it from the command line.  This executable somehow is writing an enter keystroke to the standard input, which is causing our console to exit prematurally (rather than waiting for the user to press Enter to exit).  This oddity is also visible when running the executable directly from the command line.

So the question I have is: **Is there any way to block a child process from simulating user keyboard input, or redirect that input to some other stream?**

Here is a test harness I made to help explain the problem:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  //In the full version this code resides in a worker thread that is kicked off for each piece of work that comes in,
  // resulting in a rogue enter key stroke every time something is worked.
  Process process = new Process();
  ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
  {
    FileName = @"D:\PathTo\WorkerProcess.exe",
    Arguments = "-misc parameters",
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true
  }
  process.StartInfo = startInfo;
  //Before starting this process I want to set something that will block this process from simulating any kind of user keyboard input
  process.Start();
  process.WaitForExit(10000);
  string processConsoleOutput = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); //Normally processConsoleOutput gets sent to a log file
  process.Close();

  Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit.");
  Console.ReadLine(); //This is picking up the rogue enter that the user did not type resulting in exit
}
```

Comment: You talk about redirecting input. Have you tried that? I mean you already redirect output here and its the same thing for input already. See https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput

Comment: @Ralf Yes, I have looked at RedirectStandardInput and I have tried different values with it, but (assuming I am understanding it correctly) RedirectStandardInput is for managing what the child process' receives from standard input not what it is sending to standard input.  My problem is that the child process is simulating input that is being sent to standard input.

Comment: Do you know how the WorkerProcess does it? Then we might have ideas. I would assume if it uses something like keybd_event or SendKeys for sending an ENTER it will be captured by the currently focused window. So you may try giving focus to someone else instead of your app or console window. Or simply wait for something more specific then just ENTER for your own app to exit it.

Comment: Unfortunately we do not have access to the source code, only thing we know is that it was likely written in C++.

Comment: Then perhaps you share the _actual_ name of the program so others can perform testing.

Comment: @user246821 the program was a custom one off executable by some sub contractor that no longer exists, and the source code has long since been lost, and I am not allowed to share the executable either, so no point in giving the actual name.  Also I am hoping for a generic answer so that if others encounter this odd situation that the answers could still help them.

Comment: @Anketam: In that case, please describe what the application is for and does, as well as, add some sample output to your post.

Comment: You may find some code that you can try by clicking on my username, and then in the search box, after my userid, type: _process_.

Comment: @user246821 Thank you.  I took a look and tried a few things I found in them, but the issue was still present.  At this time I am going to just change our code to "Press ESC to exit" rather than "Press Enter to exit" and call it a day.  The alternative is looking like I will have to do something rather extreme to sandbox this, which likely would not be worth the effort.